# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wanda'

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-pptx, magickwand, imagemagick-identify

I am trying use to create an image with logo on it I have "logo.png" and try to add logo in multiple images and add into the ppt using pptx in python but I have problem about how to install wand module in my pc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

open windows cmd,

type: "pip install wand"
If now many lines of text appear, it should have worked. But if it prints that pip command could not be found, retry it in your python directory using "cd" command than use the first.

Answer (score 0):

To install the wand module, open a terminal window/command prompt, type either:

```
pip install wand
```

or

```
pip3 install wand
```

`pip3` is for when you are working with python3 but have python2.x installed as well. `pip` is for most other cases. Is is always good to be aware of which python version you are currently working with and which versions you have installed. That way you know for which python installation you have to install a module when you need to.

Also, some programming IDEs (like Visual Studio Code) sometimes use their own isolated python installation, separate from the one installed on your operating system (OS). In that case you have to run the above commands inside of the terminal of the IDE, not in the terminal of the OS.